# Одновременный выбор нескольких значений из одного поля одной таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, выборка, параметры

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Нужно сделать параметрический поиск товаров на сайте.
Есть 3 MySQL-таблицы (приведу сокращенное количество полей):

```
1. positions (Товары)
id - идентификатор (bigint 20)
code - код товара (int 10)
rubric_code - код группы товаров
name - наименование (varchar 255)
```

```
2. products_params (Параметры товаров)
id - идентификатор (bigint 20)
name - наименование (varchar 255)
```

```
3. products_params_values (Значения параметров товаров)
id - идентификатор (bigint 20)
product_code - код товара (bigint 20)
param_id - идентификатор параметра (bigint 20)
value - значение (varchar 255)
```

Моя задача: сформировать правильный SQL-запрос, который будет искать товары,
содержащие определенные параметры посредством логического **И (AND), а не ИЛИ (OR)**

Мне удалось написать следующий SQL-запрос, но он осуществляет поиск товаров по
логическому **ИЛИ (OR)**:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT `positions`.`id`
FROM
    `positions`

LEFT JOIN `products_params_values`
ON `products_params_values`.`product_code` = `positions`.`code`

WHERE
    `positions`.`rubric_code` = '16291'
AND
    `products_params_values`.`param_id` = '1290' AND `products_params_values`.`value` IN('smd 0805')
OR
    `products_params_values`.`param_id` = '1326' AND `products_params_values`.`value` IN('17','35','40')
```

В данном случае подзапросы с условиями значений параметров:

```
`products_params_values`.`param_id` = '1290' AND `products_params_values`.`value` IN('smd 0805')
```

содержат 100 товаров

```
`products_params_values`.`param_id` = '1326' AND `products_params_values`.`value` IN('17','35','40')
```

содержат 3 товаров из эти 100

Если в последнем подзапросе **OR** заменить на **AND**, то товаров не будет найдено. Данный запрос находит 100 товаров. А должен 3.
Как осуществить поиск с применение именно **AND**?
Что я тут делаю не так?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!
Буду невероятно признателен!

Comment: почему 2 условия у Вас для `products_params_values`.`value` ? так число или строка?
вложенный запрос не нужен. очень мало когда можно оправдать вложеный подзапрос во WHERE
такое чуство, что Вы писали запрос по какому то примеру

Comment: Потому-что нужно найти 2 условия

Comment: комбинируйте AND и OR. OR при наличии AND используется в скобках.


вопрос уточняющий я задал, потому что мне непонятен тип для `products_params_values`.`value`
`products_params_values`.`value` IN('smd 0805')
`products_params_values`.`value` IN('17','35','40')
так строка или число?

Comment: Тип поля, как написано в самом начале -  varchar 255

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, как комбинировать OR и AND

Comment: например
SELECT `positions`.`id` FROM `positions` LEFT JOIN `products_params_values` ON `products_params_values`.`product_code` = `positions`.`code`
WHERE `positions`.`rubric_code` = '16291' AND (`products_params_values`.`param_id` = '1290' OR `products_params_values`.`value` IN('smd 0805')
OR `products_params_values`.`param_id` = '1326' OR `products_params_values`.`value` IN('17','35','40'))

то есть условие, должное быть обязательным выносите за скобки и добавляете AND

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение: нужно подключать таблицу со значениями параметров саму на себя столько раз, сколько запрашивается параметров.

```
 SELECT
    `positions`.`code`
FROM
    `positions`

LEFT JOIN `products_params_values` AS `ppv_1`
ON `ppv_1`.`product_code` = `positions`.`code`

LEFT JOIN `products_params_values` AS `ppv_2`
ON `ppv_2`.`product_code` = `positions`.`code`

WHERE
    `positions`.`rubric_code` = '16291'
AND
    `ppv_1`.`param_id` = '1290' AND `ppv_1`.`value` IN('smd 0805')
AND
    `ppv_2`.`param_id` = '1326' AND `ppv_2`.`value` IN('35','17','40')
```

Comment: а value таки строка) огород какой

Comment: value - строка. Это было мною указана в самом начале.